# Image is not showing in JSP File

Tags: java, image, spring-mvc, jsp, netbeans

I am having problems displaying an image in my `.jsp` file.

The image `no_image.jpg` is located inside the following directory of my Spring MVC application:

```
SpringProject\src\main\webapp\assets\images\no_image.jpg
```

I am trying to access it through my .jsp file like this:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/images/no_image.jpg"></a>
```

Project structure (using apache Netbeans IDE 11):

[image]

However this does not seem to display the image, does anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. For anyone else experiencing this issue, a possible solution is to put the following into your spring configuration `.xml` file: (Where you define your base package for the project, my one is named `spring-config.xml`)

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Expression Language is treated as plain text. To tell the JSP engine to process such expressions, add `<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>` before the `<html>` tag in your JSP page (at the top, where you have other "%@"-like directives or JSTL imports). Unfortunately, this parameter's value defaults to true.